# Ancient literature, folklore, mythology- is it appropriate to ask questions here?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have already read [this](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-questions-about-mythology-here).

However I want to know if it is okay to ask a question such as "What references to **something** exists in ancient literature, folklore, mythology?"

Would that be acceptable here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming **something** is a historical person/place/thing, that seems reasonable. Examining references to events in ancient sources is essentially what historians do.

Now if **something** is a fictional construction, it might be a bit more problematic (and there might be better stacks for the question too).

Comment: Thanks, understood. Yes I did mean person/place/thing but not exiting only in the past. But yes you've answered my question.

Comment: For a fictional construction, SciFi.SE is your huckleberry.

Comment: @DVK - For some questions perhaps. But I'm not sure they'd like to field questions about something like the trials of Hercules.

Comment: @T.E.D. - I don't think it's offtopic as long as an effort is made to either narrow down the source (Disney vs Plautus) or present it as analysis.