# Is it on topic to ask about this religious practice?

Tags: support, scope

From a historical novel, some Scandinavian peoples were practicing a form of divination, called Wands. They were presented as similar in purpose to modern-day Tarot cards.

*Can I create a question of did such a custom or practice existed?*

<sub>First two google results are IRRELEVANT(assume a single stick, while the novel described them as about 7). [1](http://www.tarotforum.net/showthread.php?t=204035) [2](http://thepaganstudygrouppage.tumblr.com/post/83922831867/how-wands-can-be-used-in-divination).</sub>

<sub>[This question asks about mythology and the andser is no.](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-questions-about-mythology-here)</sub>

<sub>[This question concludes on things that really happened ar ok.](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/811/ancient-literature-folklore-mythology-is-it-appropriate-to-ask-questions-here)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

*Update after clarification in comments:  It seems the real question is the procedure for this divinatory practice. I suspect that that is off topic. Explanations of religious ritual are likely to be either informed by belief, or require book length answers to be rigorous.*

I think you are on topic if you ask whether the practice existed. On the other hand you have two google results that confirm that the practice exists; if that was what you wanted to know, the question is answered.

I suspect you want to know more about the practice - *how* it was practiced and what it meant to the practitioners.  While these are technically questions of historical interest (if we replaced "divination by wands" with "Dietary use of mutton" or "horse racing" or "marriage customs" I don't think anyone would question the historical legitimacy of understanding those things), I lack the confidence that we would have a consensus that the question is on topic.

Excellent topic for discussion in meta.

Comment: Oops, you can see in my edited question that the google results are bad. They describe some forum threads on what to do whit a single scepter. However, i nthe book, the Wands are described as 7 pieces of wood, each with a sign ot in. The one, who is divining, throls the stick on the ground and by which lyes over which gets input for a divination.